# If 1=='1' //true and 1==true //true then why 1=='true' //false

Tags: javascript, equals

Why is `1=='true'` false?

If `1=='1'` is true and `1==true` is true.

If JavaScript compares only values not the types in the `==` scenario.

Comment: @user1805928 Because `true != 'true'`...?

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this question is down voted. The poster asked a valid - and very educative - question that would help a lot while bug fixing. If you think this question is silly - or obvious, I encourage them to give an answer and explain instead.

Comment: Please look at the following... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571451/equality-of-truthy-and-falsy-values-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because of type coercion.

In effect, this is what JavaScript is trying to do on your behalf when using the `==` operator.

```
1 == Number('true'); // 1 == NaN

1 == Number('1'); // 1 == 1

1 == Number(true); // 1 == 1
```

**When two different types are compared using `==`, JavaScript attempts to coerce them to the same type for comparission.**

You can read more about the algorithm here: http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

Comment: Thanks **Josh**, for valuable inputs.