# Unable to see the correct value by using && operator

Tags: javascript

hi i am preparing for js interview.
i saw this question.

if `var a=2, var b =3`  What would be the value of `a&&b`?
The answer given is **3**.

I am not able to understand why is this the answer.
Can you help..
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## && and || do not create true or false. They return one of the operands.

The binary operators do NOT behave like other c based languages. See more about [truthy and falsey values here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571451/equality-of-truthy-and-falsy-values-javascript)

---

`&&` is defined as follows.

> If the first operand is truthy then the result is the second operand. Otherwise it is the first.

#### Examples

```
false && true      // false the first operand is falsey
0 && true          // 0. 0 is a falsy value so the first value is used
1 && 0             // 0. The first value is truthy 
                   // so the second value is used
'hello' && 'world' // 'world' the first value is truthy 
                   // so yield the second value.
```

`||` is defined as follows.

> If the first operand is truthy then the result is the first operand. Otherwise it is the second.

#### Examples

```
false || true      // true, first value is falsey so yield second
0 || true          // true, first value is falsey so yield second
1 || 0             // 1, first value is truthy use it.
'hello' || 'world' // 'hello', first value is truthy so yield it.
```

---

## `&&` and `||` are "Short-circuit"

This means that there are ways to structure code such that not all expressions are evaluated. This can be convienient at times but is double edged.

```
function launchNukes() { /* TODO */ }
0 && launchNukes(); // nukes do not fire
1 && launchNukes(); // nukes fire
0 || launchNukes(); // nukes fire
1 || launchNukes(); // nukes do not fire
```

Answer (score 1):

&& is an AND operator, just like most everywhere else. Most languages, JavaScript included, will stop evaluating an AND operator if the first operand is false.

You can read it like that:

- if `a` is true , return value will be `b`
- if `a` is false , return value will be `a`

So && return values of operands not `false` and `true`.

for your example,

```
2 && 3 // return 3 because 2 is true
```