# Rules for Converting string and number to Boolean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I read this in [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html) book:

> The rules for converting *strings* and *numbers* to *Boolean* values state
>   that **0**, **NaN**, and the empty string **("")** count as **false**, while all the
>   other values count as **true**.

Because of this, expressions like `0 == false` and `"" == false` are **true**.

And also following these rules this expression should evaluate to true:

```js
console.log("A" == true)
```

But it evaluates to **false**.
Why?

Comment: You are not actually casting string `"A"` to boolean; you're comparing a string and a boolean, which is a different thing and it's definitively not solved by casting the left operand to the type of the right operand. If you check the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571570/13508) in the linked question, I reckon that rule #10 applies.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Actually, rule 7 applies: `x == ToNumber(y)` > `"A" == 1` , which is `false`, of course.

Comment: @Cerbrus Oops, yes, you're right, I overlooked that.

Comment: Now I get it. It's not about truthy and falsy. Thanks guys @ÁlvaroGonzález 
Cerbrus